# Issue with using useLayoutEffect React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-ref

Hook useEffect runs asynchronously and usually after the DOM is rendered/mounted, whereas useLayoutEffect runs synchronously and before the DOM is rendered/mounted.

Using my example useEffect, all works fine and I get desired result (I store the previous value that the user has entered using useRef).

But using my example useLayoutEffect, I don't get the wanted result, cause it just works as useEffect in my case. I reckon that it should firstly update `prevName.current = name` and only after render causing the same value that person has entered. I think, that in that case both `prevName.current` and `name` should be rendered as same values. But that doesn't happen.

Can you please explain why?

***Here's codesandbox:*** [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-proskuriakova-qomzrc?file=/src/App.js:0-573)

Here's the code:

```
import React, { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [name, setName] = useState("");
  const prevName = useRef(name);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    prevName.current = name;
  }, [name]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        value={name}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setName(e.target.value);
        }}
      ></input>
      <div>Your name is {name}</div>
      <div>Your previous name is {prevName.current}</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Hook useEffect runs asynchronously and usually after the DOM is rendered / mounted, whereas useLayoutEffect runs synchronously and before the DOM is rendered / mounted.

Both of them occur after the changes have been put onto the DOM. What's special about layout effects is that if you set state during the layout effect, the resulting render will be done synchronously. For normal effects, if you set state, it will rerender soon, but not synchronously. If you never set state (as in your example), it's not going to make much difference which one you use.

The most common application of useLayoutEffect is that you want to render once, measure the stuff on the dom, and then render again without the user seeing the temporary stuff you had on the dom.

Comment: But in react documentation it is said that UseLayoutEffect works similar to componentDidMount ([docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#uselayouteffect)), so it stops putting changes onto DOM, before executing a callback, passed to it. And I still don't get why in my case it doesn't work properly?

Comment: `But in react documentation it is said that UseLayoutEffect works similar to componentDidMount (docs)` That's true. It's also true for useEffect. `so it stops putting changes onto DOM, before executing a callback, passed to it` I don't know why you think this. Neither useLayoutEffect, nor componentDidMount will stop putting changes onto the dom. Both of them happen *after* changes are put on the dom

Comment: `And I still don't get why in my case it doesn't work properly?` The function component begins executing. You call useLayoutEffect and tell react "hey react, after you're done rendering, please call this layout effect code". React takes note and then continues executing your function. You create some divs and return them. React then checks what you returned, and updates the dom to match it. Now that the dom has been updated, your layout effect gets called. It is too late to change what your component returned. If you want to re-render, you can set state.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your `babel.config.js` has the runtime set to automatic:

```
"plugins": [
  ["@babel/plugin-transform-react-jsx", {
    "runtime": "automatic"
  }]
]
```